# Webmail config - default address reply from address as the address mail was sent to

Tags: webmail, squirrelmail, roundcube

Cpanel webhosting allows a "default address" to be set to forward all mail to. So the following is true.

spam1@domain.com goes to other@domain.com
spam2@domain.com goes to other@domain.com
spam3@domain.com goes to other@domain.com

This allows the flexibility to use *@domain.com whenever a disposable email is desired and at the same time enable checking all email from one account.

I wish to be able to reply to email sent to spam1@domain.com without creating an account for it, such that I can simply reply from spam1 from my other mail account.

The reason I ask the question is that I currently import all my mail into a gmail account, and the gmail account can be configured to send mail as an address after the spam1 address has been verified. I want to move away from gmail and use my own hosting instead and at the same time be able to use this reply from the sent to address.

Currently availible I have horde, squirelmail and roundcube but am more than open to trying other webmail software thats installable over ssh jailed shell access or ftp. (Shared hosting)

Alec

Answer (score 0):

If you're importing all of your mail into gmail, then it sounds to me like you have the ability to log in to the domain.com mail-server to fetch and send mail. This is important.

The most direct way to get what you're asking is to use a stand-alone email client like Thunderbird rather than a webmail system of some kind. The flow of what you need to do:

1. Log in to your SMTP server (you're already doing this to send mail) as other@domain.com
2. Send email with the From: address set to Spam2@domain.com

To get this, you'll need to create separate mail profiles in your mail client. The server information stays the same, as does the login info. But what changes is the answer to "what is your email address". In this way you'll be able to impersonate any number of virtual addresses in your domain.

Comment: I was really hoping for a server side solution so that it would be portable.